# Has my bash script crashed?

Tags: bash, shell, error-handling

I have a bash shell script, that should:

1) check for the existence of a file

2) If file exists exit script, otherwise create file

3) Set off a process

4) Check process has run correctly - and send result to a log file

5) Delete file

6) Exit script

```
if [ -f $PROPERTIES_HC ]
 then               
 # lockfile/propertiesfile exists so exit the script
 log --------- lockfile exists so operation cancelled at `date` ---------

 exit 1
else
 # no lockfile/propertiesfile so continue

 # create the lockfile/propertiesfile

 input="./$PROPERTIES_VAR"
 while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
  eval "echo $line" >> $PROPERTIES_HC
 done < $PROPERTIES_VAR

 #Run Process

 RUN_MY_PROCESS --overridefile $PROPERTIES_HC >> $LOG_FILE

 #Check Process Ran Okay

 if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then
  echo "RAN WITHOUT ERROR" >> $LOG_FILE
 else
  echo "SOME ERROR!" >> $LOG_FILE
 fi

 # Remove the lockfile/propertiesfile

 rm -rf $PROPERTIES_HC
fi
```

This script seemed to have been running fine, however recently I came across a situation where the "RUN_MY_PROCESS" element of the script failed, and the script seems to have simply exited leaving the lockfile in place.

As I understand it unless I set something like `#!/bin/sh -e`, the script should run on regardless of errors. Have I misunderstood how shell scripts/shell error handling work (I am new to this!), or is it that my shell script has crashed itself - hence it didn't finish running?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: With which error has your script crashed?

Comment: This script is run as a daily cron job. In the log file, all I can see is that the Process itself has failed (the process has creates sends its own info to the log)  - however it clearly crashes out directly after this - i.e. it never gets to the point where the script checks whether the process ran okay or not.

Comment: Can you run this script manually? You can also do it with `set -x` and get every line of execution.

Comment: I can - but the it runs fine now... The failure occurred on Saturday morning, and therefore the script did not run on Sunday or this morning - but it ran fine as soon as I removed the lockfile and reran it manually.

Comment: I suppose the clearer question is - looking at the script as it currently is, would you expect the lock file to be removed in all circumstances - or are there logical reasons as to why it might not get to that part of the script, other than the script crashing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to handle errors inside your script (i.e. errors that cause your script to crash) is through [traps](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html).

You could modify your script as follow :

```
if [ -f $PROPERTIES_HC ]
    #your regular script here
    #...

    #Run Process
    trap 'echo "SOME ERROR" >> $LOG_FILE && rm -rf $PROPERTIES_HC' ERR
    RUN_MY_PROCESS --overridefile $PROPERTIES_HC >> $LOG_FILE

    #rest of your script here
    #....
```